# How to use spotify Image Class?

Tags: html, spotify

I want to use  [Image Class](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/Image.html) to represent images in my app.
I have tried but not able to use it.
So can anybody tell me how to use this **Image class**
or provide link example to demonstrate the use of Image Class.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var views = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/views');
var img = new views.Image("mySource", "spotify:track:3LlKwQG4h83iKmDe6ftjzA", "myTitle");
> img.node
<a href=​"spotify:​track:​3LlKwQG4h83iKmDe6ftjzA" title=​"myTitle" class=​"sp-image sp-image-loaded" style=​"background-image:​ url(sp:​/​/​yourapp/​mySource)​;​ ">​</a>​
```